# GWT UiBinder: onClick event does not fire

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Hallo folks,

I have a widget defined as follow:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:HTML ui:field="rootElement" styleName="{resources.mainStructure.widgetBox}"/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

and in the related java class there's something like this:

```
@UiField HTML rootElement; 

for(int row = 0; row < 10; row ++) {            
    rootElement.getElement().appendChild(new MyWidget().getElement());
}
```

where MyWidget is something like this other:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>

<table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="{resources.mainStructure.areaWidget}"> 
     <tbody class="{resources.mainStructure.workArea}"> 
       <tr>
         <td ui:field="td_1"/> 
         <td ui:field="td_2"/> 
         <td ui:field="td_3"/> 
         <td ui:field="td_4"/> 
         <td ui:field="td_5"/> 
         <td ui:field="td_6"/> 
         <td ui:field="td_7"/> 
         <td ui:field="td_8"/> 
       </tr> 
     </tbody> 
     <tfoot class="{resources.mainStructure.lineaBus}"> 
       <tr> 
         <th ui:field="th_1"/> 
         <th ui:field="th_2"/> 
         <th ui:field="th_3"/> 
         <th ui:field="th_4"/> 
         <th ui:field="th_5"/> 
         <th ui:field="th_6"/> 
         <th ui:field="th_7"/> 
         <th ui:field="th_8"/> 
       </tr> 
     </tfoot> 
 </table>
```

At some point I attach to a certain td another widget, this one:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>

    <g:Anchor styleName="{resources.mainStructure.orangeButton}" ui:field="selectMe">+</g:Anchor>

</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Now, the problem is that when I click the anchor of the above widget, no click is fired. If I attach the anchor widget to another widget,not to the td one, it works fine. 
So far I understand the problem is in the first widget, because if I attach MyWidget to nothing than the "selectMe" onclick event is fired. Any comment?
Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, not sure how you structured it. So as I understood it you wan't the output to be sort of like this:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    ...
         <td ui:field="td_1">
            <g:HTMLPanel>
                <g:Anchor styleName="" ui:field="selectMe">+</g:Anchor>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
         </td> 
    ...
```

In the ui binder class where I created the selectMe anchor I just added an UiHandler like following:

```
@UiField Anchor selectMe;
@UiHandler("selectMe")
void onSelectMeAnchorClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.alert("clicked on selectMe");
}
```

This triggered the the alert for me when I click on the link. Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually, the real case is slightly different and I forgot to mention it (cause I thought it was unnecessary, but from your test I understand that the problem is there). I will edit the question with more details.

Comment: The problem is the HTML widget, it didn't work for me either. So I replaced it with a VerticalPanel and swaped the appendChild method with "rootElement.add(new MyWidget());"

Answer (score 3):

Be careful using calls like...

```
rootElement.getElement().appendChild(new MyWidget().getElement());
```

The 'appendChild(...)' method is nothing more than a basic DOM attachment; it doesn't do any of the work for event propagation.  Is there a reason you're not using the Widget add method()?

```
rootElement.add(new MyWidget());
```

That should work, and will line up all the events you need.

Comment: Oops... just re-read the comments in Emil's answer and noticed he said the same thing.  Nothing to see here... move along....

Comment: Or, in another similar case, `RootPanel.get().add(new MyWidget());`